# Confirm message by recover function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a button for recovering email template. So that you can choose if you want to have the original template back, or you will stick with the changes in the default template. The confirmation dialog is shown. But if I click on cancel then too the template will go to his original default value, what not has to be.

This is  jQuery for the button:

```
 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Wijzigen", "EmailTemplate", new { area = "Salaris", id = Model.Id, orgToepassen = true })&type=' + '@(Model.Type)';
```

and this is the jQuery for the confirmation dialog:

```
  $('#herstel-standaard').click(function () {
            if (window.confirm('Weet u het zeker？')) {
                $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
            }


            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Wijzigen", "EmailTemplate", new { area = "Salaris", id = Model.Id, orgToepassen = true })&type=' + '@(Model.Type)';
        });
```

and this is the HTML for the button:

```
 @ButtonHelper.Button(ButtonType.Default, ButtonSize.Large, "Herstel standaard mail", id: "herstel-standaard", icon: "glyphicon-refresh")
```